# AC 220v Single Phase Motor Control using relay

Tags: arduino, relay, motor-controller, single-phase

i've been looking for a diagram for motor control using arduino and relays, and i only found tutorials using DC motors. i know you can use a contractor but for my project i want to be able to use Bluetooth and buttons as well as an LCD display, anyway i've already got everything setup and working, i only got a few questions.

1.) Would it kill a relay if i use a 1HP 220v 8a single phase motor to drive a bridge forward,(it's about 1200 lbs not that sure yet though hehe)

2.) is there a diagram for forward reverse using a 2 channel relay?

Comment: Something tells me that you should better not touch 220VAC just yet.

Comment: Single Phase motors are reversible. For some. https://woodgears.ca/motors/reversing.html

Comment: Consider a 40A relay

Comment: @GregoryKornblum, you guys said i shouldn't touch 220VAC just yet well yes it's true my experience with Electrical stuff isn't that much, and my course is totally not related to Electrical or Electronics but how would you learn if you wouldn't try right? i mean i always wonder why electricians don't get zapped when they hold two wires directly from the main breaker until i tried it myself and realized that if you hold only one line you're safe as long as you don't hold / touch any form of ground, that's also why i'm asking for the expert's opinion about the matter. to learn more

Comment: You can experiment, indeed. But some results may be lethal. So it's better to first leard the subject, it's a very well known stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) Would it kill a relay if i use a 1HP 220v 8a single phase motor to drive a bridge forward,(it's about 1200 lbs not that sure yet though hehe)

A relay used to energize any motor must be rated for motor duty. It must be capable of handling the motor inrush current. It must be capable of disconnecting an inductive load. It must be capable of opening in the event that the motor is stalled. Knowing the weight is not the only requirement for determining the motor power rating. The friction load must be determined. The friction load includes the friction in the entire drive train including gears etc. used to reduce the speed. Gear losses can be as much as half the load, sometimes more. Not being sure is not a joking matter.

> 2.) is there a diagram for forward reverse using a 2 channel relay?

The reversing connections for an AC motor depend on the motor design. Some are not reversible at all. The ones that are reversible require the reversing of the starting or auxiliary winding with respect to the main winding. Universal motors (commutator AC motors) require the reversing of the field with respect to the armature.

Comment: i see i see so what about a solid state relay for arduino? is there such a thing?

Comment: Louie, Charles is telling you that you need to specify your requirements properly. Then you can start looking at solutions.

Comment: well as of the moment i'm still prototyping my retractable bridge, so i'm just looking for something that could handle heavy load, so i found this one [Solid State Relay](https://ph-live.slatic.net/v2/resize/products/S-6885-05d6073f4f4f7943576ac6c610635dc9.jpg)

Comment: The specs look good for the Fotek SSR-40 DA. When you link a product, it is best to link the specs rather than a picture. http://www.fotek.com.tw/pdf/etc_34.pdf  Note that the specs appear to require the pictured heatsink. Using SSRs for reversing duty is quite risky.

Comment: @LouieJayOrellanaJayme - I am not getting involved with your question, I just wanted to help you with some experience: **Beware**, there are *many* fake (i.e. counterfeit) SSRs, especially those which are falsely labelled with the Fotek brand, like in the photo you linked. Only buy from reputable, traceable sources (i.e. not Ebay and similar) if you want to be confident of getting a "real one".

Comment: @CharlesCowie could you explain why reversing on SSR is risky? even if i use two of them? thanks!

Comment: @SamGibson i see, any brand you can recommend?

Comment: Reversing with SSRs is risky because you are depending on the circuit controlling the SSRs to prevent two SSRs for opposite directions from being turned on at the same time creating a short circuit through the SSRs. An H bridge created with 4 SSRs will not necessarily have the required level of electronic short circuit protection.

Comment: @LouieJayOrellanaJayme - "*any brand you can recommend?*" The problem isn't with the brand; it's with the sale of counterfeit devices. From previous research, I saw that Fotek SSRs were often counterfeited in certain marketplaces, but other brands might be too (I don't buy SSRs often enough to know). That's why I recommended to always buy from traceable sources - same applies to any brand, since any brand *might* be counterfeited.

Answer (score 1):

2.) is there a diagram for forward reverse using a 2 channel relay?[image]

Alternating current motors are either induction start-induction run, capacitor start-induction run, or capacitor start-capacitor run motors. AC motors may be single voltage or dual voltage motors with one or two run windings respectively. The run windings on dual voltage motors, i.e., 110/220 volt motors, are connected in parallel or series depending on the system voltage. The direction of rotation of an AC motor depends on the magnetic polarity of the start winding. Reversing the polarity of the "Start" winding, in relationship to the "Run" winding, reverses the direction of rotation of all single-phase alternating current (AC) motors.

[image]

Comment: The OP's motor is single-phase. Given the OP's lack of knowledge on this subject your answer isn't going to help much. You can edit to improve. Look at Charles Cowie's answer for reference.

Comment: is the example a relay or are you referring to a Contactor? because if that's a Contactor then there's no way i could hook that up to my arduino and expect it to magnetize, or i could if i'd use a relay but that's just too much redundancy i think

Comment: Amos - Welcome :-) Since you copied those diagrams from somewhere, you need to [reference them correctly](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) otherwise you could be accused of plagiarism. For a diagram, then adding a link to the source web page where you found it is sufficient; if you copied them from a book, then title, page, author & publisher are needed. To help you see an example, here is a [random answer of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/356850/101852) and you can see the "Original source" link below the image which I copied from an application note.

Comment: Louie if you do not understand relay logic than I will stand with Gregory Kornblum comment  "you should better not touch 220VAC just yet."

Comment: Sam thank you but have a look at the bottom of the diagram (Source: Delmar/Cengage Learning.)

Comment: @AmosDeCarmo - Yes, I saw that (although when I started writing, I noticed that your previous diagram had *no such info* :-) ) - but even that text on the current images does not meet the requirements of the site rules that I linked for you. That info complies with the 3rd point ("*Provide the name of the original author*") but you have not complied with the 1st point ("*Provide a link to the original page or answer*"). Just add a link to the web page where you copied them from, and you meet the site rules, and everyone is happy :-) Do you *really* want to keep arguing with the site rules? ;)

Comment: This diagram shows one common reversing scheme. There is another scheme in which the capacitor is switched from one to the other of two identical windings.

Comment: @AmosDeCarmo You have posted two identical diagrams. Did you have another alternative that you intended to post?

Comment: Seems to me you are the only one not happy. No need to  argue. I am leaving this site it is to PC for me. Good day

Comment: Charles yes I had a alternative diagram but it seams to me you have to be PC to post diagrams. I do not wish to step on anyone toes so I will just but out.

Comment: @samGibson that is one of the reason why I change the post to the second diagram and also it was a diagram for a 3 phase zig zag delta controller for you info. Not single phase capacitor start induction run Single phase capacitor start,capacitor run,  split phase motor and or a shaded pole motor.  First diagrams author you would not be leave me so what is the point. Thank you!!

Comment: Not everyone is particular about "borrowing" generic diagrams from un-referenced sources. However posting something is a form of publishing and pasting someone else's diagram is a copyright infringement. It is not about politics.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) Would it kill a relay if i use a 1HP 220v 8a single phase motor to drive a bridge forward,(it's about 1200 lbs not that sure yet though hehe)

Why reinvent the wheel.

> i know you can use a contractor but for my project i want to be able to use Bluetooth and buttons as well as an LCD display

Use a smart relay from schneider, omron, allen bradley or any know reliable company with a IEC or NEMA rated motor starters / contactor.

[image]

Comment: Page 188 of the [datasheet](https://www.idec.com/language/english/manual/FL1AManual.pdf) shows that the contact rating is severly derated for non-resistive loads: *Fluorescent tubes with electr.
control gear (25,000 switching
cycles)
10 x 58 W (at 230/240 V AC)*". That's only 580 W. Again, the OP doesn't appear to have enough knowledge to use the information you have provided.

Comment: Look at my Answers again " Use a smart relay from schneider, omron, allen bradley or any know reliable company "WITH" a IEC or NEMA rated motor starters / contactor."  WITH a IEC or NEMA rated motor starters / contactor Thank You.

Comment: The smart relay will control the motor starter. The smart relay has a LCD Display, push buttons and some have and can be Bluetooth  control. Plus if he has little experience working with line voltage, this is a safer way for him. I am a retied UL approve control panel designer and manufacture.  (UL 508A)    Thank You.

Comment: *I* know how to wire them and I understood your answer. (I'm an industrial controls engineer.) My point is that the OP obviously doesn't. I'm encouraging you to improve the answer so it's useful to the OP.

Comment: @Transistor if you know, why ask? " (I'm an industrial controls engineer.)" Good for you, I'm a retired industrial controls engineer, UL approve control panel design engineer, Field service engineer , Licensed Master Electrician, certified control panel manufacture, PO2nd Class Construction  Electrician that is still learning something new every day. That is why I like our trade, you never stop learning, Right. :)

Comment: @LouieJayOrellanaJayme Using SSR is a bad Idea. You can not be sure that the forward and reverse SSR would not be energize at the same time as per Charles Cowie Comment. You would also not have a mechanical interlock. It is good practice to have both a electrical and mechanical interlock when controlling motors of this nature.

Comment: @AmosDeCarmo for the interlock, i've already set that up on the software side, using arduino's digital pins, which i've set and made sure that when the other button is pressed the other one has a value of 0, i guess the only problem now would be if the SSR is truely rated at 40A right?

Comment: @AmosDeCarmo okay if all else fails, the SSR and the relays is really a bad idea and the only way is to use a contactor is it fine if i swap the buttons with a 2 channel relay? the relay will act as the buttons since i can control this relay from arduino.  i know you need an AC power source so with that in mind i can't directly use the contactor with arduino, and of course the interlocking wires would be present as well as the overload relay. although this would be the all else fails option for me. thank you for the answers it has given me some idea.

Comment: @LouieJayOrellanaJayme Yes the SSR is a very bad idea. The reason you need a motor stater type Relay/Control is for the  Protection it provides you/operator and the equipment. Go and have a look at this link https://www.schneider-electric.com/en/product-category/3000-motor-starters-and-protection-components/ and you will see for you self. Now you can use a 2 channel Relay for the buttons. But don't you have other limits that need to be incorporate into your design? A smart relay with a motor starter would be the best way to go in my opinion. It would be safer also for you or the operator.